# Node.js: failed to remove the key from the object

Tags: node.js, error-handling

I have this really simple authentication method. I am trying to remove the `loginPassword` from the `item` object before sending the response.

But, unfortunately its not working.

```js
const auth = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    var item = await __auth(req.body.loginId);

    if (! item || ! await bcrypt.compare(req.body.loginPassword, item.loginPassword)) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        type: 'validations.exception',
        code: 'users.auth.001',
        errors: [{
          loginId: 'Invalid `Login id` or `Password`',
          loginPassword: 'Invalid `Login id` or `Password`',
        }]
      });
    }

    const tokens = __jwtTokens({ loginId: item.loginId });
    const authToken = await __updateRefreshToken(item._id, { 
      tokens: tokens.refreshToken 
    });

    delete item.loginPassword;

    return res.send(item);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).send({
      error
    });
  }
};
```

Received response

```js
{
  "_id": "645dd4da1bdd4ad4a1f1e91a",
  "firstName": "...",
  "lastName": "...",
  "email": "...",
  "emailVerify": null,
  "emailVerifiedAt": null,
  "mobile": 9876543210,
  "mobileVerify": null,
  "mobileVerifiedAt": null,
  "loginId": "...",

  "loginPassword": "REMOVE_THIS_FROM_THE_RESPONSE_OBJECT",

  "status": true,
  "uuid": "..."
}
```

Required response

```js
{
  "_id": "645dd4da1bdd4ad4a1f1e91a",
  "firstName": "...",
  "lastName": "...",
  "email": "...",
  "emailVerify": null,
  "emailVerifiedAt": null,
  "mobile": 9876543210,
  "mobileVerify": null,
  "mobileVerifiedAt": null,
  "loginId": "...",
  "status": true,
  "uuid": "..."
}
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: You're not showing what `item` actually is. If it's a Mongoose document, for example, you can't use `delete` on it because they aren't regular objects.

Comment: it's likely if delete doesn't work then `Object.defineProperty` has been used with `configurable: false` to define the object, its good practice, If you what to edit the object you'll need to copy it first, place `item = {...item}` above the delete line, though personally id move the becrypt check into `__auth` method, its likely you only using becrypt there and its auth related, then its a simple `if (!item){` check, and you can exclude the loginPassword from being returned by the `__auth` method if its not used anywhere else, I suspect __auth is just abstraction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why the answer was removed. But, it did actually solved the problem.

Mongoose was returning the document object instead of json object.

Here is the working code:

```js
const auth = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    var item = await __auth(req.body.loginId);

    if (! item || ! await bcrypt.compare(req.body.loginPassword, item.loginPassword)) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        type: 'validations.exception',
        code: 'users.auth.001',
        errors: [{
          'loginId': 'Invalid `Login id` or `Password`',
          'loginPassword': 'Invalid `Login id` or `Password`',
        }]
      });
    }

    const tokens = __jwtTokens({ loginId: item.loginId });
    const authToken = await __updateRefreshToken(item._id, {
      tokens: tokens.refreshToken
    });

    item = item.toObject();

    delete item.loginPassword;

    return res.send(item);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).send({
      error
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: "_Not sure why the answer was removed._" it was most likely generated with ChatGPT or the like. Such answers may be right or sometimes totally wrong. But it is difficult to tell apart, as they are expressed with the same authoritative tone and look well researched with examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
{loginPassword, ...safeObject} = item
```

Now `safeObject` is the object you can send as the response.

Comment: Thanks @DrHerreman. But, `safeObject` is an exact replica of the `item`. Therefore, it doesn't solve the problem.